# Nested Lists Linq to return 1 definitive list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a list that contains a nested list ie.

```
public class Question
{
  public string Question { get; set;}
  public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
  public string TagName { get; set;}
  public string TagDescription { get; set;}
}
```

We then have a procedure where GetQuestions() returns a list of questions

```
public List<Tag> QuestionTags(int Type)
{
DAQuestions da = new DAQuestions();
var t = (from d in da.GetQuestions(Type)
               )
                select d.Tags).ToList();
}
```

What we are trying to achieve it to return back 1 definitive list of tags (no duplicates).

What we have returning at the moment is a

```
List<List<Tag>>
```

Comment: Use `SelectMany` to Flatten your `List<List<Tag>>` and implement `IEqualityComparer<Tag>` to get distinct values from that list. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
da.GetQuestions(Type).SelectMany(q => q.Tags).Distinct().ToList();
```

`Distinct` relies on query provider to filter out identical tags, so it depends on OR/M that you use.